# cascade delete / reference update with simonVT Schematic

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

For database and content provider generation I´m using SimonVT Schematic (https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic). I couldn´t find the possibility for configuring a cascade delete (there is @References but no cascade option). Is it missing or possible to configure somehow?

Another problem, in one table one column is referencing the column of another table:

```
@DataType(TEXT) @NotNull @References(table = PlaylistsDb.PLAYLIST, column = PlaylistColumns.NAME) String PLAYLIST = "playlist";
```

Now when I change the referenced column NAME in the table PLAYLIST I would expect that in the referencing table the referencing column PLAYLIST would automatically update, but it doesn´t. Is this configurable?

Answer (score 0):

**First part of you question**

> I couldn´t find the possibility for configuring a cascade delete
>   (there is @References but no cascade option)

There is no such option. In order to verify it you can look at [References annotation](https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic/blob/master/schematic-annotations/src/main/java/net/simonvt/schematic/annotation/References.java) and [TableWriter implementation](https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic/blob/master/schematic-compiler/src/main/java/net/simonvt/schematic/compiler/TableWriter.java) (just search for `cascade`, there is no occurrences).

I suggest to create a feature request, if you really need it.

For **the second part** I need clarification first.

> when I change the referenced column NAME

Please, specify what do you mean by this (which change exactly you do and show the result that you expect)